# How Can I change Session save path?

Tags: magento-2.1, session

How can i change session save path? I need to save session data to my project folder, how can i change session save path?.thanks in advance for your valuable answers..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You can change session save path from file /app/etc/env.php**

```
'session' =>
   array (
     'save' => 'files',
     'save_path' => '/var/www/session',
),
```

Read magento Doc for more info:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/sessions.html

Comment: I put this code but am getting an exception warning like below

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/www/session/sess_qumuvadijl0ovpq7p3r5varfq0, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /var/www/html/WC/Magento-CE-2.1.10-2017-11-04-12-49-09/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22

Comment: i set save_path correctly and issue cleared